# decode('utf-16') does not decode correctly

Tags: python

I have the utf-16 string `\u0423\u043a\u0440\u0430\u0438\u043d\u0430`. This encodes `Украина`, you can verify it with any online utf16 decoder.

But trying to decode it in python:

```
print(b"\u0423\u043a\u0440\u0430\u0438\u043d\u0430".decode('utf16'))
```

outputs: `畜㐰㌲畜㐰愳畜㐰〴畜㐰〳畜㐰㠳畜㐰搳畜㐰〳`

Why?

Comment: \u escapes are only for text strings, not byte strings

Comment: That bytestring is literally the bytes "\", "u", "0", etc.

Answer (score 4):

That's not a "utf-16" string, its just a regular unicode-escaped string. `print("\u0423\u043a\u0440\u0430\u0438\u043d\u0430")` prints out the correct output without needing to decode anything.

However, if you actually have a bytestring with the literal bytes "\", "u", "0", "4", etc. for some reason, use `print(b"\u0423\u043a\u0440\u0430\u0438\u043d\u0430".decode("unicode-escape"))`.

Comment: It was very nice to test your code and see the output exactly this time :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have `"\u0423\u043a\u0440\u0430\u0438\u043d\u0430"`, then that doesn't "encode" `Украина`; it *is equal to* `Украина`. It is not "a utf-16 string"; it is *a string*. There is *no such thing as* "a {name of encoding} string".

There *are* "bytes which encode a string using ". `bytes` objects are not text. Strings are not byte sequences. They are not meaningfully related types, and only appear to be for legacy reasons (Relatively unfortunate ones, honestly; the first Unicode standard was closer in time to the first ASCII standard than to today.) In that light, the literal syntax for `bytes` objects, as well as their canonical `repr`, is rather unfortunate; but that's what we have to live with.

If you have `b"\u0423\u043a\u0440\u0430\u0438\u043d\u0430"`, then you have a `bytes` object, created using a literal. The literal syntax for `bytes` does not assign any particular meaning for `\u` escapes. The `u` in `\u` stands for Unicode. In a string, that sequence represents a Unicode code point. `bytes` objects cannot contain those - they contain *bytes* - so there is no reason for them to support the escape sequence. As usual for things that Python encloses in quotation marks, a backslash followed by something with no special meaning, is just a backslash (even though you normally should double up backslashes to escape them). Of course, within a `bytes`, a backslash symbol doesn't represent the backslash text character, because `bytes` objects don't store text. Instead, for those historical reasons, it represents the integral value 92.

If you want to create a `bytes` object that contains bytes which represent a string in UTF-16 encoding, then:

- Determine whether you actually mean UTF-16-LE or UTF-16-BE. It is necessary to choose.
- for each Unicode code point of the string, if it's in the [Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), find the corresponding 16-bit value; for other characters, use a [surrogate pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates) of two such values.
- For each 16-bit value, represent it as two bytes, with the order determined by the desired endianness (-LE or -BE).
- For each of those bytes, represent it in the `bytes` literal syntax with a `\x` escape sequence (backlash, lowercase x, and two hexadecimal digits). (Or use the corresponding ASCII character, if applicable.
- OR, create a list (or other iterable) of the byte values, and pass it to the `bytes` constructor.

If you want to *read bytes from a file* that represent a UTF-16 string, assuming you know the endianness, then it's simple:

- Open the file in binary mode and read whatever number of bytes.
- To get the corresponding string, use the `.decode` method of the `bytes` object.

If you have `b"\u0423\u043a\u0440\u0430\u0438\u043d\u0430"` and wish to treat it as `"\u0423\u043a\u0440\u0430\u0438\u043d\u0430"`; and for some reason you cannot fix the process which gave you this bad input, then that is what the `unicode-escape` codec is for.